# zplane command shows strange zero locations for FIR filter

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I have created a lowpass filter FIR with Matlab and get some strange zeros in the zplane when I vary the filter order.

I have used Matlabs builtin `fir1` function to calculate the filter coefficients in the following way:

```
sampling_rate=100;
cutoff_freq = 5;
filter_order=80;
b_l=fir1(filter_order,cutoff_freq*2/sampling_rate);
zplane(b_l);
```

If the filter order is < 80, the zplane diagram looks like this:
[image: Zplane Diag. of lowpass filter with filter order 79]

but if the filter order is >= 80 one zero is at about -6.5*10^14:
[image: Zplane Diag. of lowpass filter with filter order 80]

What does Matlab do to calculate the filter coefficients and how comes that a pole is lies so far from the unit-cycle?

Comment: Not sure if that answers the question fully, but according to the doc on `fir1`, this is the reference it uses to compute the filter coefficients: Programs for Digital Signal Processing, IEEE Press, New York, 1979. Algorithm 5.2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't really clarify, why the zero is so far away from the unit circle.
I took the filter coefficients fir1 returned and calculated the roots with Mathematica and no root had such a big absolute value so I guess that some kind of rounding errors happen within the zplane function...but I don't really know..

Comment: I have tried the same code in Octave 3.8 and I don't get the same problem with the (very) negative zero. I have tried filter orders of 80, 85 and 90.

Comment: Mhm, it seems to be a bug in the Matlab implementation...if I use  the code I posted, I get the plot above...if I use 85 or 90 it works.
I tried different filter orders and it seems, that my previous assumption was wrong...there are low filter orders that give me such a strange pol/zero-plot (which is obviously wrong) and quite high filter orders where everything works as it should.
Thank you for checking it with Octave!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The strange pole-/zero-diagram which results from executing the code in Matlab R2013a seems to be the consequences of a bug in the `zplane` function.

According to the comments, Octave 3.8 shows a different pole-/zero-diagram using the same code.

I used the filter coefficients created by `b_l=fir1(filter_order,cutoff_freq*2/sampling_rate)` to construct a polynomial and find its roots using Mathematica. Non of the roots had a big absolute value, so the plot has to be erroneous.